# Simple feature linestring collection not visible in R leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, openstreetmap, r-sf

I am trying to display a simple feature collection of (disconnected) linestrings in R using `sf` and `leaflet`. The data is obtained from openstreetmap using `osmdata`.

Using the base plot()-function, `tmap`, or `mapview`, I am able to directly display the linestrings on a static and interactive map. However, this does not work using `leaflet`. Leaflet correctly centers the map, but does not display the linestrings. Fiddling with color, weight, etc. parameters in addPolyLines() does not seem to help.

**Reprex**

```
library(osmdata)
library(leaflet)
library(sf)
library(tmap)

osm <- opq(bbox = c(-0.27, 51.47, -0.20, 51.50)) %>%
  add_osm_feature(key = 'name', value = "Thames", value_exact = FALSE) %>%
  osmdata_sf()

osm$osm_lines

Simple feature collection with 2085 features and 178 fields
geometry type:  LINESTRING
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -2.029917 ymin: 51.37841 xmax: 0.6778926 ymax: 51.79032
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
First 10 features:
...

plot(osm$osm_lines, max.plot = 1) # OK
qtm(osm$osm_lines) + tm_lines() # OK
mapview(osm$osm_lines) # OK

leaflet(osm$osm_lines) %>% # not OK (grey)
  addPolylines()
```

**Session-info**

```
> library(sf)
Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.2.3, proj.4 4.9.3
Warning message:
  package ‘sf’ was built under R version 3.4.4 

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
  [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
  [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
  [1] tmap_1.11-2   sf_0.6-3      leaflet_2.0.1 osmdata_0.0.7

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] httr_1.3.1         viridisLite_0.3.0  jsonlite_1.5       splines_3.4.3      geojsonlint_0.2.0  foreach_1.4.4      R.utils_2.6.0      gtools_3.5.0      
[9] shiny_1.1.0        expm_0.999-2       sp_1.3-1           stats4_3.4.3       yaml_2.1.19        LearnBayes_2.15.1  lattice_0.20-35    digest_0.6.15     
[17] RColorBrewer_1.1-2 promises_1.0.1     rvest_0.3.2        colorspace_1.3-2   plyr_1.8.4         htmltools_0.3.6    httpuv_1.4.3       Matrix_1.2-12     
[25] R.oo_1.22.0        XML_3.98-1.11      rmapshaper_0.4.0   raster_2.6-7       gmodels_2.16.2     xtable_1.8-2       webshot_0.5.0      scales_0.5.0      
[33] gdata_2.18.0       satellite_1.0.1    later_0.7.3        gdalUtils_2.0.1.14 mapview_2.4.0      magrittr_1.5       mime_0.5           deldir_0.1-15     
[41] R.methodsS3_1.7.1  nlme_3.1-131       MASS_7.3-47        xml2_1.2.0         class_7.3-14       tools_3.4.3        geosphere_1.5-7    stringr_1.3.1     
[49] V8_1.5             munsell_0.5.0      compiler_3.4.3     e1071_1.6-8        classInt_0.2-3     units_0.6-0        grid_3.4.3         tmaptools_1.2-4   
[57] RCurl_1.95-4.10    dichromat_2.0-0    iterators_1.0.9    htmlwidgets_1.2    crosstalk_1.0.0    bitops_1.0-6       base64enc_0.1-3    boot_1.3-20       
[65] codetools_0.2-15   DBI_1.0.0          jsonvalidate_1.0.0 curl_3.2           R6_2.2.2           lubridate_1.7.4    rgdal_1.3-2        rgeos_0.3-28      
[73] spdep_0.7-7        KernSmooth_2.23-15 stringi_1.1.7      osmar_1.1-7        Rcpp_0.12.17       png_0.1-7          spData_0.2.8.3     coda_0.19-1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

osmdata has named features, which leaflet cannot read. See https://github.com/ropensci/osmdata/issues/100

As a hack you can set names to NULL:

```
osm_lines <- osm$osm_lines
names(osm_lines$geometry) <- NULL
leaflet(osm_lines) %>%
  addPolylines()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it started showing lines, but mas stopped being visible